# Can't get discord bot to send an image from a local folder

Tags: python, discord

I'm trying to get this discord bot to send an image with the same filename as the user input. `

This is what I have

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
folder_name = "testing"

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')

# Greetings
@bot.command()
async def hello(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send(f'Hello {ctx.author.name}!')

# Messing with math
@bot.command()
async def add(ctx, num1: int, num2: int):
    result = num1 + num2
    await ctx.channel.send(f'The sum of {num1} and {num2} is {result}')

@bot.command()
async def send_file(ctx, image_name):
    file_path = '/Users/user/Documents/Projects/Discord_bot/testing/' + image_name + '.png'
    await ctx.channel.send(file=discord.File(file_path))

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Instead of the bot sending the image with the filename specified, I'm met with this error:
`Command raised an exception: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/user/Documents/Projects/Discord_bot/testing/cat.png'`

The file exists and I've checked the path multiple times and it seems to match up with the path provided by the `pwd` command.

Comment: try adding the absolute path (c:/folder/file.extension)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the cross-platform hell.
I don't know which platform Python is running on, but try using pathlib or os.path for path manipulation to handle cross-platform scenarios.

```py
import os

path1 = 'path/to/some/dir'
path2 = 'file.txt'

# Join two paths
joined_path = os.path.join(path1, path2)
print(joined_path)
```

Output (on Unix): `path/to/some/dir/file.txt`
Output (on Windows): `path\to\some\dir\file.txt`

upd

```py
class discord.File(fp, filename=None, *, spoiler=..., description=None)
```

This means that you should use one of the following options:

```py
with open(joined_path, "r") as fd:
   await ctx.channel.send(file=discord.File(fd))
```

or:

```py
await ctx.channel.send(file=discord.File(filename=file_path))
```

Comment: At the moment I'm using OSX to run the bot, and I intend to use a unix server to host it on. The path generated by the code you provided is the same path I'm trying to use but it still isn't able to fetch the file.

Comment: u can try use
path = Path("relative/path/to/file.txt")
absolute_path = path.resolve()
Also check that the program has enough rights to open and read the file

Comment: upd:
read [doc](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=file#discord.File)